# PHP GD inappropriate transparancy

Tags: image-manipulation, transparency, gd, alpha-transparency

When i cropped a png image using php gd library it cropped in a strange way. As it is partially cropped. I think the transparency is not working properly.

Here is my code

```
      imagesavealpha($this->image, true);
      $bg = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
      imagefill($this->image, 0, 0, $bg);
      imagepng($this->image,$filename);
```

Comment: The other thing you're supposed to do on Stack Overflow is maintain a professional decorum. Try describing your problem in *words*, rather than a picture. The better you can do that, the more the community will trust you, and the more privileges you will gain. Besides that, this isn't even a real question: it's impossible to tell what's being asked here.

Comment: A little less profanity and a little more description of what's going on will do wonders...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you like you are giving your new image the wrong size.

How do you crop the image? `imagecopyresampled`?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php